# PHP Number String Mask

Tags: php

Hi how to convert this string -> 9123456789 to  -> (+639) 123 456 789. Im using PHP.

```
$value = '9123456789';

function numberMask($value) 
{
     return $value
}
```

I want to return the value in this format: (+639) 123 456 789

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I think it's not the full set of conditions for this task. Does this string always have same length? Do you need to add always code 63 in the beginning?

Comment: yeah. The value has the same length and needs to add +639 in the beginning.

Comment: do you want to add this for `Philippines` or `Canada` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you always have string with same length which always starts with **9**, then you can do the following:

```
function numberMask($value)
{
    unset($value[0]);
    return '(+639) ' . join(' ', str_split($value, 3));
}
```

If the string may starts not from **9** you can do the following:

```
function numberMask($value)
{
    $start = $value[0];
    unset($value[0]);
    return '(+63' . $start . ') ' . join(' ', str_split($value, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like this

```
$value = '9123456789';

function numberMask($value) 
{
  $value =  array_reverse(str_split(strrev($value),3));
  $value[0] = "(+63".$value[0].")";
  return implode(" ",$value);
}

echo numberMask($value);
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1050120)

Output :

```
(+639) 321 654 987
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I found the answer to my question, I will answer it.

```
function numberMask($value)
{
  $value = substr($value, 1);
  return '(+639) ' . join(' ', str_split($value, 3));
}
echo numberMask(9123456789);
```

The output will be (+639) 123 456 789

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
  *  9123456789 to (+639) 123 456 789
  *  1. Create a string that does not have first char i.e 123456789
  *  2. insert a space after every 3rd char -> 123 456 789
  *  3. Append first char i.e -> 9 to mask i.e +63
  *  3. format the string to (+639) 123 456 789
  */
function numberMask($value, $mask = '+63')
{
  // get the first charecter 
  $first = $value[0]; var_dump($value, $first);
  $value = substr($value, 1);
  // space after 3 numbers
  $last = join(' ', str_split($value, 3));
  return "($mask$first) " . $last;
}
echo numberMask('9123456789'); // (+639) 123 456 789
echo numberMask('9123456789', '+91'); // (+919) 123 456 789
```